# Pinterest OAuth Redirect Uri not working

Tags: oauth, pinterest, python-social-auth

I've been trying to get the pinterest api working on my project but I keep running into an issue with the redirect_uri. This is the error message I am getting.

```
{
    status : "failure",
    code : 7,
    host : "coreapp-ngapi-prod-0a018ab7",
    generated_at : "Sat, 15 Apr 2017 00:45:16 +0000",
    message : "You are not permitted to access that resource.",
    data : "The provided redirect_uri https://example.com/complete/pinterest/ does not match any of the registered redirect URIs."
}
```

I am running my site on https. I have https://example.com/ set as the site URL and https://example.com/complete/pinterest/ in the redirect uri (I've make sure to enter that so it's in the list, and save the page)

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried not adding the path to the redirect list, also have you verified spelling?

Comment: I've tried removing the redirect path as well as double checking all the spellings of everything. I've also tried removing the railing slash on the urls/

Comment: If you're sure you've registered it correctly and using https then try contacting Pinterest support

Comment: Oh, hot damn. It looked like pinterest wasn't actually saving my changes to the redirect uri. I would make a change, hit save, and occationally reload the page which would still show the changes I'm making but would never work. I later left that page to look at some of the docs, then returned to find that no changes were ever actually saved. Now redoing all that, it works.  I live across the street from 3  pinterest offices so they'll be getting some frowny faces whenever I walk by to work.

Comment: glad I could help, if you don't mind please mark my answer below as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of it to give me a few points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure you've registered it correctly and using https, then try contacting Pinterest support

Comment: Im not sure if it was a weird fluke with pinterest, but their save button wasn't actually working. When leaving the developer page and re-entering, I found that no changes were saved during that session.

Comment: @ReimusKlinsman i have too faced the same problem. whether i need to get any approve from pinterest development team for my app? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new Redirect URL on the Pinterest Developer board, you have to be sure that:

- it is an HTTPS URL
- it is correctly spelled
- and **VERY IMPORTANT**:   **remember to press the *ENTER* key** when you have finished to write the Redirect URL.  The newly inserted URL will then appear under the text field and the classical "you have unsaved changes" will appear.
- Click on the "Save" button and you are done.

Hope it helps.